SMTPAuthenticationError - basic authentication is disabled for outlook.live.com for personal hotmail account
I have a Python code that sends me email for notification. It stopped working around Oct 1st, 2024. I checked the error and it is pretty self explanatory:

SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled.
[MW3PR06CA0022.namprd06.prod.outlook.com 2024-10-05T17:16:11.773Z 08DCE50B06703488]')

Then I researched and the answer is to use OAuth2 for authentication. In order to do that, I need to register an app in Azure Active Directory or Entra ID. I logged in to the Azure portal (with my personal email account) and click on Entra ID, I got this error:
{
  "sessionId": "4081aae14bea491097f866fbc809fc5d",
  "errors": [
{
      "errorMessage": "interaction_required: AADSTS16000: User account &#39;{EUII Hidden}&#39; from identity provider &#39;live.com&#39; does not exist in tenant &#39;Microsoft Services&#39; and cannot access the application &#39;74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6&#39;(ADIbizaUX) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account. Trace ID: e4c76820-5005-42a5-a10d-e862cb662700 Correlation ID: 8b7358b6-c2e9-4f7d-b743-f7e6cef91143 Timestamp: 2024-10-05 17:37:31Z",
  "clientId": "74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6",
  "scopes": [
    "a57aca87-cbc0-4f3c-8b9e-dc095fdc8978/.default"
  ]
}

More research suggested that I am using a personal account and not a work/school account so I should use https://identity.microsoft.com/ for that. I went to the website and looked around and it is pointing me back to Azure AD again... So basically, I am in a loop.
Is Microsoft forcing everyone to pay for an Azure subscription now, or am I missing something? Thanks!

I have the same issue, did you made it?

@RodrigoSantamaria, no. I followed schmark's advice to generate an App password but still not working. I didn't try too hard though. I just switched to Gmail which worked fine for me.

Microsoft is phasing out App Passwords, and it may not be available for all accounts.
But in some cases, Microsoft allows users to create App Passwords as a fallback for older applications that don’t support Modern Authentication. This is a randomly generated password you can use in place of your normal password.
Here’s how:

Go to Microsoft Account Security Settings.
Enable Two-Step Verification (if not already done).
You should now see an option to create an App Password.
Use this App Password in your python/script email for SMTP authentication.

Another option might be to check the auth-settings of your email-client. This blog-post gets into more details

Thanks @schmark. I enabled the MFA and created the App password. I tried again but still getting the same error: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [MW4PR03CA0098.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2024-10-09T15:09:35.396Z 08DCE76B8E2B473F]'). Do I just use the new app password in place of my main hotmail password, or should I change my smtp code as well? Thanks

Hi, did you used your App password instead of your email password?

This didn't work for me either, were you able to fix it Difan?
